# Why does overriding GetHashCode() block INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, winforms, inotifypropertychanged

I have a *dead* simple view model that inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged`. After attempting to create some automated tests for this view model, I ended up overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`. My tests passed, so I was a happy camper.

However, now my Windows Forms data bindings aren't reacting to when a property in my view model changes. If I comment my `GetHashCode()` implementation all works as expected, except for my tests.

Here is my implementation:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hashCode = (_subject != null ? _subject.GetHashCode() : 0);
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (_message != null ? _message.GetHashCode() : 0);
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^
                   (_body != null ? _body.GetHashCode() : 0);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

This is simply what ReSharper generated for me.

Why does overriding `GetHashCode()` stop my data bindings from picking up on my view model changes despite me calling the `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: Are GetHashCode() and Equals() operating on the same fields?  In other words, if Equals() returns true, the HashCodes should be equal.  Can you verify that's the case?

Comment: My guess is the hash code being returned is the same each time, so .Net thinks its the same object and doesn't fire the property changed event.

Comment: Very Unclear. What data bindings?  ViewModels for WinForms? And why do tests require GetHashcode ?

Comment: @Ryan: I believe you're correct.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: The data bindings that I set up on my Windows Forms controls. The data binding support isn't as rich as WPF, but it still works. My tests needed `GetHashCode()` because I was comparing 2 view models.

Comment: @JG in SD: I took your suggestion and implemented `IEqualityComparer<T>` in my test project. Your comment is very true since the equality functionality is not needed in production. The issue is now fixed. You can post your comment as an answer if you wish. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always try to avoid adding code to production code that is solely for testing purposes. So since you implemented `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for testing purposes, would it be possible to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` and use that in your unit tests to performs the assertions.